# How to include some dependencies before executing maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven

I have one problem as follow:

In file pom.xml of the project

I would like to add some dependencies to my project before packing the project into a jar file

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includeArtifactIds>
                    <!-- some depedencies -->
                </includeArtifactIds>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/somewhere</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generateSingle</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-full</finalName>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies </descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But after executing maven install then the jar file still does not contain the dependencies which maven-dependency-plugin created. I have tried to change some phase in maven-dependency-plugin but the result also is not change.

Comment: the dependencies you need are available to project ?

Comment: Why do you need the dependency plugin? The jar-with-dependencies can locate artifacts within your local repo.

Comment: Yes, it's available in my local repository

Comment: @rlegendi: I need some dependencies (jar file) move to another place in the project